# Recognizing paragraphs and applying styles

Tags: feature-request

I believe this question may have already been asked, but unfortunately I have not found something similar.

Does anyone have a good tip on how can I create notebooks from the **mathematica.stackexchange.com** pages?

My way is very bad:

1º - I select, with the mouse, the parts referring to the `texts` of the web page.

2º - In the notebook, I click <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to set the cell as `text`.

3º - I select, with the mouse, the parts referring to the `Codes` of the web page.

4º - In the notebook, I click <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to set the cell as `Input`.

I do this procedure for every paragraph on the page. This is very exhausting.

[image]

Is it possible to automate this process one way?

Some kind of file that when imported the program recognizes the desired style and applies?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-copy-paste-text-interspersed-se-code-snippets-into/3537#3537